# How to invoke loadNibNamed without losing UISwipeGestures?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xib, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm loading a different xib when the user flips to landscape and that's working great, but I've noticed that my swipe events aren't registered.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if ([self currentlyInLandscapeMode:toInterfaceOrientation]) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotosLandscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }else{
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PhotosPortrait" owner:self options:nil];   
    }
}

- (BOOL)currentlyInLandscapeMode:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

How can you switch xib's and keep all the state from my previous view/xib?

**UPDATE**

turns out my IBOutlets still work but my swipe isn't registered

Comment: Are the iboutlets properly wired in the second xib?

Comment: yes -the landscape started as a copy of the port view so everything in the xib is identical except the location on the view itself (xy coords)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a nib file to lay out existing objects. A nib file is stored as an archived object graph, so when you load a nib, either with `NSBundle`'s `loadNibNamed:` or `UIViewController`'s `initWithNibName:`, a fresh set of objects gets instantiated.

The only way around this would be to use `loadNibNamed` to instantiate a new set of objects, and use their `frame` properties to set the `frame`s for your existing objects, which isn't a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to re-register the swipe event after each nib is loaded (like so)

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if ([self currentlyInLandscapeMode:toInterfaceOrientation]) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VotePhotosLandscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }else{
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VotePhotosViewController" owner:self options:nil];   
    }
    [self wireupSwipeEvents];
}

- (BOOL)currentlyInLandscapeMode:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}

- (void)wireupSwipeEvents
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release]; 
}
```